# Angular custom filter with promise inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angular-promise

What I am trying to achieve is using a filter that will return success or error from the `ret()` function. With the code below it returns `{}`, which is probably its promise.

```
.filter('postcode', ['$cordovaSQLite', '$q',
function($cordovaSQLite, $q) {
    return function(PostCodeID) {
        function ret() {
            var def = $q.defer();
            ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
                if (window.cordova) {
                    var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
                        name: "msddocapp.db"
                    });
                } else {
                    var db = window.openDatabase("msddocapp.db", "1", "ES Database", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
                }
                var query = "select * from PostCode where ServerID = ?";
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [PostCodeID]).then(function(s) {
                    if (s.rows.length > 0) {
                        def.resolve(s.rows.item(0).Title);
                    }
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    def.reject(PostCodeID);
                })
            });
            return def.promise;
        }
        return ret().then(function(s) {
            return s;
        }, function(e) {
            return e;
        });
    }
}]);
```

This filter is used for only one `ng-repeat`, so maybe I can bind a function to ng-repeat like:

**HTML**

```
{{getPostName(item.id)}}
```

**Angular.js**

```
function getPostName(id) {
    return post[id].name;
}
```

Comment: filter needs to be synchronous. How are you planning to use this?

Comment: I got ID of PostCode in DB need to Get Value of it and put in place of ID like id = 1 then value is 00-000

Comment: What you are writing is a service, not a filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment

> I got ID of PostCode in DB need to Get Value of it and put in place of ID like id = 1 then value is 00-000

You need to use a directive in order to make the call to the database and perform the DOM manipulation.

http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

**Directive:**

```
angular.directive('postcode', ['$cordovaSQLite', '$q', function($cordovaSQLite, $q){
    return {
        template: '{{getPostName(item.id)}}',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.getPostName = function(PostCodeID) {
                var def = $q.defer();
                ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
                    if (window.cordova) {
                        var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
                            name: "msddocapp.db"
                        });
                    } else {
                        var db = window.openDatabase("msddocapp.db", "1", "ES Database", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
                    }
                    var query = "select * from PostCode where ServerID = ?";
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [PostCodeID]).then(function(s) {
                        if (s.rows.length > 0) {
                            def.resolve(s.rows.item(0).Title);
                        }
                    }, function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                        def.reject(PostCodeID);
                    })
                });
                return def.promise.then(function(s) {
                    return s;
                }, function(e) {
                    return e;
                });
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-postcode></div>
```

***EDIT:***

Since this particular directive is sharing the scope with its parent you just need to edit the template to use whatever you are passing in, `i` in this case:

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in data.contacts">
    <td>
        <div data-postcode></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Directive**

```
template: '{{getPostName(i.id)}}'
```

Comment: could you tell me how to use directive as filter?

Comment: You do not need to use a filter. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: and how to pass i.PostCodeID if i got this ng-repeat:
  <tr ng-repeat="i in data.contacts">
<td><div data-postcode>{{i.PostCode}}</div></td>
</tr>

Comment: not working it returns {{getPostName(item.id)}} and 
ReferenceError: PostCodeID is not defined

Comment: I just copy and pasted your code to give you an example of a directive using it. I edited my answer to use `scope.getPostName = function(PostCodeID)` instead of `scope.getPostName = function(id)`