# Angular custom directive with promise not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a `directive` based on [Angular custom filter with promise inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833536/angular-custom-filter-with-promise-inside). I tried defining a `filter`, with the same result.

The issue is that I always get `{}` as the value, whenever I use a promise.

The following simple example shows the issue very clearly.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('convert', ['$q', function ($q) {
    return {
        template: '{{convertFunc()}}',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.convertFunc = function () {
                var def = $q.defer();
                def.resolve('test');
                return def.promise.then(function (s) {
                    return s; // debugger doesn't stop here
                }, function (e) {
                    return e; // debugger doesn't stop here
                });
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <div data-convert></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Can you help finding out what am I doing wrong?

### Edit

[This is the plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jXcPM64mTKDBrdemub21) I used to create the example.

### Edit 2

I'm trying to show the result of the promise on a page. In my real code I'm calling a service and then building a `string` using values from the service.

VS debugger shows that my `string` is built correctly. But I cannot display it on the page. I'm under the impression, that JS/Angular fails to recognize completion of the promise. I cannot stop on the breakpoints marked above.

Comment: Hmm..you don't have any service calls or something like that to use a promise in it's beauty? But try 'return def.promise' and 'convertFunc.then(data){console.log(data)}

Comment: you wouldn't get anything as output by returning promise on view..? what kind of feature you wanted to achieve here.?

Comment: The example was simplified to show the issue. In reality, instead of 'test' I'm calling a service. But I'm getting the same result.

Comment: @PankajParkar I'd like to convert units, based on data defined in a service. The converted unit is correct in VS debugger, but I can't get it to display. The behavior is exactly the same as with my 'test' literal. I'm getting just {} as the result.

Comment: Is your objective to show the result of the promise on the page?  Or are you using that function as a filter?

Comment: @Dave My objective is to show it on the page.

Comment: @mlemanczyk by having `convertFunc()` promise on page will have more effect on page.. as it going to evaluate on each digest cycle..which is not considered as a good practice

Comment: How about something a little simpler: http://plnkr.co/edit/e25gj1Fz62fTNPdEWxoT?p=preview  (wrapped the resolve() call in a timeout to simulate waiting on a service call)

Comment: @Dave I will try your suggestion and comment/update the question. I cannot directly use scope property, because I have multiple items on the same page. But PankajParkar is right - it could be called multiple times for the same item. I will follow your both advises and try updating item properties, instead. It will take me some time as I'm newbie in Ionic/Angular :-)

Comment: Not sure what you mean about scope.  Maybe a more complete example would be helpful.

Comment: @Dave A solution based on your example worked. The key is to "bind" the HTML element to a real object property. It seems that Angular cannot bind directly to a promise.

How can we post the answer, so that you can get the credit?

Btw. I meant this part of your example
        "scope.convertedData = s;"

Comment: I can post the code, but I'm not really sure how to explain why you should do it the way I suggested - I'm too new to angular myself.  I think we just call this a win as-is.